# Reading .env and properties.yml files based on profile in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, environment-variables

I am using `.env` and `properties.yml` files in my Spring Boot apps and need to be clarified for using them properly. After that, I will also use the other profiles of these files e.g.  `.env-dev` and `properties-dev.yml`.

Could you please explain these issues?

**1.** As far as I know, these files are automatically read based on the Run/Debug profile of Intellij or maven. If the active profile is dev, only `.env-dev` and `properties-dev.yml` files are read, if the profile is prod, only `.env-prod` and `properties-prod.yml` files are read. If the profile "dev,prod", then both of these files are read. Is that true?

**2.** What if there are only `.env` and `properties.yml` files in the project. Then, are these files always read when profile is selected or not?

**3.** Can I read environment variables from `.env` file when running/debugging app via Maven by giving file name to the following command?

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Xdebug" 
-Dspring-boot.run.profiles=dev -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="DB_NAME=employee_db 
DB_USERNAME=postgres DB_PASSWORD=******"
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252589/discussion-on-question-by-cecilia-reading-env-and-properties-yml-files-based-on); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't panic! It is/*must be* working...

Start simple:

1. [quickstart-maven, dependencies: web (only)](https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=3.0.4&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=17&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=web)
2. Just a demo (no/empty `application.properties`, *according to `foo.bar, foo.baz` we can refer to any [common](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html)/custom "property"* ;):

   ```java
   package com.example.demo;

   import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
   import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
   import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
   import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
   import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

   @SpringBootApplication
   public class DemoConfigApplication {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(DemoConfigApplication.class, args);
     }

     @Bean
     InitializingBean test(
         @Value("${foo.bar:undefined}") String fooBar,
         @Value("${foo.baz:undefined}") String fooBaz
     ) {
       return () -> {
         System.err.format("foo.bar: %s%n", fooBar);
         System.err.format("foo.baz: %s%n", fooBaz);
       };
     }

   }
   ```
3. Build

   ```bash
   ./mvnw clean test
   ```

   prints:

   ```bash
   ...
   foo.bar: undefined
   foo.baz: undefined
   ...
   ```

---

To set these via (springboot-)maven-plugin, we can:

#### ((Git)Ba)sh

1. Via "Command Line Arguments"
   (with blanks, with my win+gitbash:

   ```
   GNU bash, version 5.2.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)
   ```

   )

   **Syntax**:

   ```bash
   ./mvnw spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--foo.bar='Foo Bar' --foo.baz='Foo Baz'"
   ```

   (prints):

   ```bash
   ...
   2023-03-15T13:45:52.849+01:00  INFO 4196 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1106 ms
   foo.bar: Foo Bar
   foo.baz: Foo Baz
   ...
   ```
2. Via "System Properties" (same git bash):

   **Syntax**:

   ```bash
   ./mvnw spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Dfoo.bar='Foo Bar' -Dfoo.baz='Foo Baz'"
   ```

---

To make (e.g.) 1. work in

#### cmd.exe

(Version 10.0.19045.2673), same quoting as gitbash:

```dos
.\mvnw.cmd spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--foo.bar='Foo Bar' --foo.baz='Foo Baz'"
```

#### PowerShell

(v7.3.3)
More complicated, due to/with [ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.3):

```powershell
.\mvnw.cmd spring-boot:run '-Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--foo.bar=""Foo Bar"" --foo.baz=""Foo Baz"""'
```

...

Comment: it's getting weird (in command line (in opposite to files!)), when the values (modern passwords/keys/hashes tend to) contain (OS, shell specific) "special and quoting characters" ... ;(;(

Comment: so (e.g.) `foo.bar=!"§${ab0x!')\t\r\n *+-'System.exit(-1);\'\"""\\\ ` will be much harder to "pass via command line"

Comment: Thank you so much for this wonderful encyclopedia :) It is really useful for not only this particular situation, but also in the future and I took note the whole answer. I will try it, but before that I wanted to vote up and marked it as answer as it is written so nice and seems useful. It I have a problem regarding to this, I will post here again. Many thanks, you must be moderator on SO as an example user.

Comment: Thank you very much! There is so much information hidden/untold/auto-configured, but generally "it works"... You can ask (me/here) anytime. (Resp. the last comment on "special, escape and quoting characters" (cmd layer) + (maven plugin layer) + (maven layer) can complicate things...) Future readers/oriented developers, who struggle with this, I want to guide to (modern cloud based "secret (and config) management" a la) ["spring vault"](https://spring.io/guides/gs/vault-config/), ["docker secrets"](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/)....